# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: .... Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou tendo o seguinte alerta ao utilizar o hook `useEffect`:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'conectar'. Either
> include it or remove the dependency array
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps.

Olhei alguns tutoriais na internet, porém não achei nenhuma saída que funcionasse. O que estou fazendo errado? Segue o código problemático:

```
const Grafico = (props) => {
  const [estoqueReal, setEstoqueReal] = useState([]);
  const [estoquePrevisto, setEstoquePrevisto] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
  async function conectar() {
    const resposta = await ObterEstoque(props);

    setEstoqueReal(resposta[0])
    setEstoquePrevisto(resposta[1])
    setData(resposta[2])
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    conectar()
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (...);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema aqui, é que não fica claro usar métodos externos dentro do evento do useEffect, pois será mais complicado de mapear o que efeito precisa de informações para ser executado.

Todas variáveis e métodos precisam estar declarados no array.

O artigo a seguir explica essa questão com mais detalhes e exemplos: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

No seu caso basta colocar o método conectar dentro do useEffect conforme abaixo:

```
   useEffect(() => {
      async function conectar() {
         const resposta = await ObterEstoque(props);

         setEstoqueReal(resposta[0])
         setEstoquePrevisto(resposta[1])
         setData(resposta[2])
      }
      await conectar();
      }, [props]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta colocar o **conectar** no array, por exemplo:

```
const Grafico = (props) => {
  const [estoqueReal, setEstoqueReal] = useState([]);
  const [estoquePrevisto, setEstoquePrevisto] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function conectar() {
    const resposta = await ObterEstoque(props);

    setEstoqueReal(resposta[0])
    setEstoquePrevisto(resposta[1])
    setData(resposta[2])
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    conectar()
  }, [conectar]);

  return (...);
```